# WordPress RewriteRule works locally, but not on web server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to use a custom permalink structure for my plugin's pages, so I used add_rewrite_tag and add_rewrite_rule to accomplish this. Everything works fine on my local dev server, but on my web server I can't get WordPress to redirect properly.

After using add_rewrite_rule, my htaccess file gets updated with the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/index.php/portfolio/?portfolio_item=$1 [QSA,L]
```

On my dev server if I go to the URL 127.0.0.1/site/portfolio/testing/, this works fine. On my web server when I go to www.mydomain.com/site/portfolio/testing/, I keep getting the "This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?" screen. I was getting that error on my local dev server as well until I flushed my rewrite rules. Flushing the rewrite rules on the web server doesn't help.

If I type in the URL  www.mydomain.com/site/index.php/portfolio/?portfolio_item=1 it works OK, so the problem must be that that RewriteRule isn't rewriting correctly. But after many tests, I can see the rewrite rule is fine. It's something with WordPress.

For testing I created a phpinfo.php file and changed the RewriteRule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/phpinfo.php [QSA,L]
```

This worked. So I'm a bit stumped as to why WordPress on my web server isn't obeying this RewriteRule, but only when redirecting to index.php. Or maybe it is and there's something interfering? I'm basically stumped and I've been trying to debug this for a full day already. I could really use some help...

EDIT: Here's the full .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/index.php/portfolio/?portfolio_item=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Does your web server support custom .htaccess files.. Secondly, is it an apache based server?

Comment: It's an apache server. The .htaccess file is working. Changing the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/phpinfo.php [QSA,L]` works as expected, so the htaccess is working.

Comment: may i ask why there is an index.php/portfolio/ ?? Im not sure on your scripting but in my experience it doesnt look like a proper query. try site/index.php?portfolio_item$1

Comment: It's a proper URL. Going to /site/index.php/portfolio works fine. I'm doing it that way so it loads the /portfolio template. If I just go to index.php?portfolio_item=x it will pass the variable, but won't load the portfolio section template.

Comment: does site represent a url or a directory

Comment: it's a directory. basically a dev directory off my main domain, so www.domain.com/site/ is where wordpress is installed.

Comment: To me it looks your doing a modrewrite on top of an additional rewrite. IE, index.php/portfolio is already a rewrite. What yo need to do is copy the rewrite that wordpress uses and add an additional query into it on another line.

Comment: I'll edit the original post with the complete htaccess file. The thing is though, this same htaccess file works perfectly on my local server.

Comment: different apache versions and configs do different things in different environments

Comment: That's something I've though about. The thing is, if I change the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/phpinfo.php [QSA,L]` it works. If I change it to `RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? http://www.google.com [QSA,L]` it works. It's making me think it's something with WordPress. At first I thought /site/index.php/portfolio/ wasn't working correctly, but if I go to that URL directly it works.

Comment: ah!! take the /site off if the .htaccess is in the same directory

Comment: try this RewriteRule ^portfolio_item/([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1&portfolio_item=$2 [L]

Comment: That didn't do it :( It's the same "This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?" error page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have no idea what's going on here. I'm going to try and get another server set up and see what happens.

Comment: yea im at a loss, i can write rewrites but im not that advanced with them

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar problem, I got it figured out. Basically, I was rewriting an already rewritten URL. The original rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? /site/index.php/portfolio/?portfolio_item=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Was changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]*)/? index.php?page_id=31&portfolio_item=$1 [QSA,L]
```